# Linear Algebra - Geometrically

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book that tackles Linear Algebra but in a really Geometric way - I'm currently using Strang's book, and I like it so far, but I was wondering if anyone has any different recommendations.

Thanks!

Comment: [Shafarevich and Remizov](https://www.springer.com/gb/book/9783642309939)

Comment: LAGA: "Linear Algebra and Geometric Algebra, Alan Mcdonald, 2010". Although Strang's book is excellent.